# make text box writeable for out side object

Tags: c#, textbox, set

I am still getting the hang of the get set methods in c#, and I am trying to make a private text box writable from out side the form class.

so I have the following code.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem aboutToolStripMenuItem;
private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel2;
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;

        public textBox2
        {
          set
           {
        texbox2.text = value;
            }
        }
```

And what I want is to make it so I can update the text in text box two from the main program thread with out making the whole of textbox2 public? but can't work out how to do it?

I know the code above is completely incorrect but I hope it shows what I am trying to do.

Thank you

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare your property like this:

```
public string textBox2Text
{
    get
    {
        return textbox2.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        texbox2.Text = value;
    }
}
```

You weren't declaring a type for your property, and you were duplicating the ID of the textbox. Omit the `get` block if you don't need or want it.

Comment: ahhh!! shows i'm not a programmer don't it :) the logic is fine the syntax catches me out every time!! Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
        public string TextBoxText
    {
        get { return textbox1.Text; }
        set { textbox1.Text = value == null ? "" : value; }
    }
```